# В чем причина HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request?

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8, unicode

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос через скрипт с распарсеного Atom фида:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $item) {
 global $chatID;
 $description = $item->description;
 $description = html_entity_decode($description);
 $description = strip_tags($description);
 var_dump($description);
 $sendto    =   API_URL."sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$description;
 file_get_contents($sendto);
}
```

Выдает 400 Bad Request: PHP Warning:  `file_get_contents("текст запроса")`.
Беру текст запроса из терминала, копирую в адресную строку браузера, запрос выполняется, сообщение приходит, но все кириллические символы заменяются на коды вида: `\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432` и так далее. 
Я так понимаю это проблема с кодировкой, пробовал такие решения:

```
//$description = mb_convert_encoding($description, 'utf-8', 'utf-8');
//$description = mb_convert_encoding($description,'CP1250','Unicode');
//$description = mb_convert_encoding($description, "UTF-8", "auto");Тол
```

Толку ноль. Кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Так у вас проблема с 400 Error ? или проблема с кодировками? или то и другое?

Comment: @Арсен у меня проблема с кодировкой, из за которой запрос не отправляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В URL используется [url-кодирование](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), а вовсе не "голые символы" переведенные UTF-8 или UTF16.

Используйте функцию [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: Да, всё так. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

При использовании `file_get_contents` используйте заголовки, может помочь.

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: ru\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents('http://www.vashresurs.ru/', false, $context);
```

Если проблема с кодировкой попробуйте использовать `urlencode($str);`